# Error on deserialization with pickle python

Tags: python, pickle

I am new to python. I have a file `data.pkl`. What I would like to do is get the data from the file. I looked at http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html, 11.1.7 example and tried exactly that.
My code looks like this:

```
import pprint, pickle

pkl_file = open('data.pkl', 'rb')

data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pprint.pprint(data1)

pkl_file.close()
```

But it is giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sadiksha/workspace/python/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 966, in load_string
    raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you create the data.pkl file?

Comment: It was already provided to me!

Comment: Well, how was it created by whoever created it? Are you sure it was pickled and saved correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your pickle file was either not written correctly (specifying 'wb') or the file was somehow corrupted. Try creating your own pickle file and reading that back in. That should do the trick.

As for the pickle file specified, it is definitely corrupted.

Comment: yes you were right, the file was corrupted. It was parsing new line as '\r' which was giving the error!